# Singular Fisher Information matrix, why is it a problem

Tags: inference, fisher-information, singular-matrix

I need to perform some research on the consequence of a singular Fisher Information matrix in statistical inference.

I am confused about what kind of problems a singular Fisher Information matrix creates. I've received a paper 'Likelihood-based inference with singular information matrix' by Rotnitzky (2000) but this seems too hard for me. I don't even get past the motivating example.

I also got a paper on the skew-normal distribution where the information matrix would be singular. The paper 'Problems of inference for Azzalini’s skew-normal distribution' by Pewsey is easier to comprehend. I've tried implementing this likelihood for the so called 'direct' parameterization where $X$ is skew-normal distributed if it's pdf is given by:
$$f_X(x;\xi, \omega,\alpha) = \dfrac{2}{\omega}\cdot  \phi\left(\dfrac{x-\xi}{\omega}\right) \cdot \Phi\left(\alpha \cdot\dfrac{x-\xi}{\omega}\right)$$
Where $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are the pdf and cdf of a standard-normal.

Using the package `sn` i've implemented this as follows:

```
library('sn')

## likelihood function
skewnorm.likl <- function(theta, y){
  xi <- theta[1]
  omega <- theta[2]
  alpha <- theta[3]
  n <- length(y)
  logl <- n*log(2) +n*log(omega)+ sum(log(dnorm((y-xi)/omega))) + sum(log(pnorm(alpha*(y-xi)/omega)))
  return(-logl)
}

## testing it out
## this generates 1000 skew-normal distributions
y <- rsn(n=1000,xi=2,omega=2,alpha=10)


## trying the optimization
optim(c(0,1,5), skewnorm.likl, y=y)
```

Finding the MLE by minimizing the loglikelihood seems impossible trough calculations, these methods don't converge.

#### Questions

Could someone clarify the issue of a singular Fisher information matrix, through the implementation in `R` it seems like the issue is that finding the MLE is hard (by optimization).

On the other hand this doesn't really adress the issue of inference...
I also know how:
$$\sqrt{n}(\boldsymbol{\hat \theta} - \boldsymbol{\theta}) \stackrel{D}{\rightarrow} N\left( \boldsymbol{0}, I(\boldsymbol{\theta})^{-1}\right)$$ which also seems like an issue of $I$ is singular...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of the Rotnitzky et al. (2000) paper is (quote)

> ...to provide a unified theory for deriving the asymptotic
>   distribution of the MLE and of the likelihood ratio test statistic
>   when the information matrix has **rank one less than full** and the
>   **likelihood is differentiable up to a specific order.**

Their results depend on a parameter $s$ and its parity (odd/even), where $2s+1$ is the number of derivatives of the likelihood.
In such a situation, what happens is that depending on the parity of $s$, the statistic that has an asymptotic distribution is not the usual one (has different scaling), and the limiting distribution is not normal. See their Theorems 1 and 2 in subsection 3.4, and their comment immediately below them.

For the **Skew-normal distribution**, the Fisher Information becomes singular when the true value of the "skew" (or "slant") parameter $\alpha$ **is zero**. This means, as [Azzalini](http://www.cambridge.org/9781107029279) notes in ch. 3.1, pp 57-59, that the score test with the null hypothesis $\alpha =0$ is invalid in its usual form.

When $\alpha =0$ two of the elements of the gradient of the log-likelihood become linearly dependent, which creates the singularity.

Comment: So if I understand well: The **main** issue of a a singular Fisher Information matrix is that it implies that the usual $$\sqrt{n}(\hat \theta-\theta) \stackrel{D}{\rightarrow} N(0, I(\theta)^{-1})$$ is not valid. Rotnitzky et all gives the valid asymptotic distributions. This is important since the likelihood ratio test *uses* the asymptotic distribution. The fact that calculating the mle estimators through optimization is harder when $I$ is singular is just another phenomenon.

Comment: Indeed, since its inverse stands for the asymptotic variance-covariance matrix, when this inverse does not exist, the asymptotic distribution should be expected to somehow change.