# What's the consequences when Fisher Information Matrix(FIM) is not invertible?

Tags: references, fisher-information

From the point of the unbiased estimator, there will still be a lower bound of covariance which will have nothing to do with FIM when it's singular, so I want to know are there some references about what's the consequences when FIM is not invertible, not limited to Cramer-Rao lower bound, I just want to know as systematically as possible the consequences?

Comment: Related SE post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/273303/362671.

Comment: Also an interesting article to have a glance at: [An Interpretation of the Moore-Penrose Generalized Inverse of a Singular Fisher Information Matrix](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1944).